# Plot only specific bins in a histogram

Tags: c++, root-framework

What's the best way to plot a portion of a histogram (while preserving error data)?

For instance, I have a histogram with about 16k bins, but I'd like to only plot, say, bins 12200 - 13500. However, this histogram is made from subtracting two other histograms. So it has error data that's different from the standard Poisson error data, (I assume! If it doesn't, then I also need to figure out how to make error propagate properly.)

My approach was:

```
TH1D noBgCounts(counts - bgcounts);
auto noBgCounts_plot = new TH1D("Plot", titleString.c_str(), end_bin - start_bin, start_bin, end_bin);
for (int i = 0; i < end_bin - start_bin; ++i) {
  noBgCounts_plot->SetBinContent(i, noBgCounts.GetBinContent(start_bin+i));
}
```

And then plot noBgCounts_plot, but I'm reasonably certain looking at the return type of GetBinContent that this doesn't preserve error, so I'm left with the standard sqrt error.

I also need to fix a gaussian to this data (noBgCounts_plot), does the gaussian use the errors on the bins to formulate the errors of its parameters?  (I assume so!)  If so how do I fit only a portion of the histogram?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument of `SetBinContent` and the return value of `GetBinContent` are really only float/double, so you copy only the central value of each histogram bin. If you also want to copy the error, then `SetBinError` and `GetBinError` can be used.

In your case, where all the bins are next to each other, you're better off with [`TAxis::SetRangeUser`](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTAxis.html#ac85f8261dedc23bbe68f90afd196cdb8) or `SetRange`.

```
TH1F* h = new TH1F("h","H",100,-5,5);
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000; i ++) {
   h->FillRandom("gaus");
}
h->Draw();
h->GetXaxis()->SetRangeUser(-3,-1); // only draw axis range from -3 to -1
h->GetXaxis()->SetRange(10,15); // only draw bins 10 to 15
h->Draw();
```

When fitting with [`TH1::Fit (TF1 *f1, Option_t *option="", Option_t *goption="", Double_t xmin=0, Double_t xmax=0)`](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTH1.html#a63eb028df86bc86c8e20c989eb23fb2a), the arguments `xmin` and xmax` set your fit range.